# A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:) - angular http request with .NET

Tags: .net, angularjs

i am bring all the links of file from database but getting an error while getting the links to embedd in my html. "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)"

Here is my angular script

```
    app.controller('urlController', function ($scope, $http, idService) {
    $scope.displayMovie = function () {
        $http.get("/Movie/getLinks/", { params: {movID: localStorage.getItem('movID')} }).then(function (response) {
            $scope.linkList = response.data;
        })
    }
    $scope.displayMovie();
})
```

this is my action link in .net

```
 [ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult getLinks(string movID)
        {
            moviesOperation op = new moviesOperation();
            return Json(op.getMovieLink(movID), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

this is the link i am getting from database

```
https://openload.co/embed/dFyF2dGtLjY/
```

what i am misssing? please help!

Comment: What is the value of movID?

Comment: it is ID to bring links from database. in my case value of movID is 4, actually i am bringing all the links from database against 4